# Viewing tables in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

How can I find out which tables I have in CockroachDB? I tried looking for my schema and couldn't find that, so I'm not sure how to find out which tables I've already created or what their columns are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to find your databases (which are CockroachDB's equivalent to PostgreSQL's schemas) using either:

- MySQL-style [`SHOW DATABASES`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/show-database.html) statement
- PostgreSQL-style by querying `information_schema.schemata`. For example:

  `SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;`

Once you have the database name, you can find the tables using either:

- MySQL-style [`SHOW TABLES`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/show-tables.html) statement
- PostgreSQL-style by querying `information_schema.tables`. For example:

  `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '[database to check]';`

Once you find the tables, you can get more information about them using [`SHOW COLUMNS FROM [table]`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/show-columns.html) or the `information_schema` database.